# How to filter a list using lodash if the filter function is asynchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am new to lodash and Javascript in general. I am using nodejs.
I am using the lodash filter function to filter some contents in my collection.

Here is the snippet

```
filteredrows = _.filter(rows, function(row, index){

   //here I need to call some asynchronous function which checks the row
   //the return value of this asynchronous function will determine whether to return true or false for the filter function.

});
```

My question is, how do I do this? using a closure? Is it possible to do this within the lodash filter function?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply put: You can use an asynchronous function if the calling function expects a synchronous function. So now, you can't use `_.filter`

Comment: Yes, it's impossible with lodash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

lodash may not be the best tool for this job. I recommend you use `async`.

https://github.com/caolan/async#filter

Example: `fs.exists` is an asynchronous function which checks for the existence of a file then calls a callback.

```
async.filter(['file1','file2','file3'], fs.exists, function(results){
    // results now equals an array of the existing files
});
```

Comment: You're doing asynchronous actions! Your performance is already out the window.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accomplish this with lodash instead of installing a new library(`async`) you can do the following:

```
const rowFilterPredicate = async (row, index) => {

  // here I need to call some asynchronous function which checks the row
  // the return value of this asynchronous function will determine whether to return true or false for the filter function.

}

// First use Promise.all to get the resolved result of your predicate
const filterPredicateResults = await Promise.all(_.map(rows, rowFilterPredicate));

filteredrows = _.chain(rows)
  .zip(filterPredicateResults) // match those predicate results to the rows
  .filter(1) // filter based on the predicate results
  .map(0) // map to just the row values
  .value(); // get the result of the chain (filtered array of rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash isn't an asyncronous tool. It makes filtering information in realtime veery fast. When you need to make a process asynchronous, you must use [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html), [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async), Native promises or callbacks.

I think that you should use Lodash and Underscore, only to organize Objectdata in realtime.