# How to use Array.prototype.filter with async?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, async-await

### Background

I am trying to filter an array of objects. Before I filter, I need to convert them to some format, and this operation is asynchronous.

```
 const convert = () => new Promise( resolve => {
     setTimeout( resolve, 1000 );
 });
```

So, my first try was to do something like the following using async/await:

```
const objs = [ { id: 1, data: "hello" }, { id: 2, data: "world"} ];

objs.filter( async ( obj ) => {
    await convert();
    return obj.data === "hello";
});
```

Now, as some of you may know, `Array.protoype.filter` is a function which callback **must return either true or false**. `filter` is synchronous.  In the previous example, I am returning none of them, I return a Promise ( all async functions are Promises ).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

So as one can assume, the code before doesn't really work... That assumption is correct.

### Problem

To make filter work with an async function, I checked stackoverflow and found this topic:

[Filtering an array with a function that returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355528/filtering-an-array-with-a-function-that-returns-a-promise)

Unfortunately, the chosen answer is overly complex and uses classes. This won't do for me. I am instead looking for a more simple solution, using simple functions with a functional approach.

There is one solution at the very end, using a map with a callback to simulate a filter:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46842181/1337392

But I was hoping to fix my filter function, not to replace it.

### Questions

- Is there a way to have an async function inside a filter?
- If not, what is the simplest replacement I can do?

Comment: You could use an existing async filter function like [array-async-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-async-filter), or write your own.

Comment: It looks like the built-in filter function uses `Function.call()` under the hood to execute your filter function.  That seems likely to break the async/await bit by not calling `await`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There is no way to use filter with an async function (at least that I know of).
The simplest way that you have to use filter with a collection of promises is to use `Promise.all` and then apply the function to your collection of results.
It would look something like this:

```
const results = await Promise.all(your_promises)
const filtered_results = results.filter(res => //do your filtering here)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am new to promises, what would the your_promises parameter be? would it be my function returning a promise object?

Comment: @OmarRuder An iterable (e.g. array) of promises.

Answer (score 14):

Adapted from the article [How to use async functions with Array.filter in Javascript](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-async-functions-with-array-filter-in-javascript/) by Tamás Sallai, you basically have 2 steps:

1. One that creates the conditions for an object to pass
2. One that receives the objects and returns true or false according to conditions

Here's an example

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

const asyncFilter = async (arr, predicate) => {
    const results = await Promise.all(arr.map(predicate));

    return arr.filter((_v, index) => results[index]);
}

const asyncRes = await asyncFilter(arr, async (i) => {
    await sleep(10);
    return i % 2 === 0;
});

console.log(asyncRes);
// 2,4
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) fromArray/toArray methods...

```
const result = await scramjet.fromArray(arr)
                             .filter(async (item) => somePromiseReturningMethod(item))
                             .toArray();
```

as simple as that - here's a ready example to copy/paste:

```
const scramjet = require('../../');

async function myAsyncFilterFunc(data) {
    return new Promise(res => {
        process.nextTick(res.bind(null, data % 2));
    });
}

async function x() {
    const x = await scramjet.fromArray([1,2,3,4,5])
        .filter(async (item) => myAsyncFilterFunc(item))
        .toArray();
    return x;
}

x().then(
    (out) => console.log(out),
    (err) => (console.error(err), process.exit(3)) // eslint-disable-line
);
```

Disclamer: I am the author of scramjet. :)

Answer (score 4):

Build a parallel array to your array which you want to call filter on.
Await all of the promises from your filter func, in my eg, `isValid`.
In the callback in `filter`, use the 2nd arg, index, to index into your parallel array to determine if it should be filtered.

```
// ===============================================
// common
// ===============================================
const isValid = async (value) => value >= 0.5;
const values = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6];


// ===============================================
// won't filter anything
// ===============================================
const filtered = values.filter(async v => await isValid(v));
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));


// ===============================================
// filters
// ===============================================
(async () => {
  const shouldFilter = await Promise.all(values.map(isValid));
  const filtered2 = values.filter((value, index) => shouldFilter[index]);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered2));
})();
```

This behavior makes sense since any `Promise` instance has a truthy value, but it's not intuitive at a glance.

Answer (score 4):

This answer uses library [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops), which handles iterable objects, and supports async filtering:

```
import {pipeAsync, filter, toAsync} from 'iter-ops';

// your input data:
const objs = [{id: 1, data: 'hello'}, {id: 2, data: 'world'}];

const i = pipeAsync(
    objs,
    filter(async value => {
        await convert(); // any async function
        return value.data === 'hello'; // filtering logic
    })
);

for await(const a of i) {
    console.log(a); // filtered data
}
```

---

P.S. I'm the author of [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops).

Answer (score 3):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method can mimic *filter* and can operate with promises.

```js
const isPositiveNumberAsync = async (number) => number >= 0;

const filterPositiveNumbersAsync = async (numbers) => numbers?.reduce(async (accumulatorPromise, number) => {
  const accumulator = await accumulatorPromise;

  if (await isPositiveNumberAsync(number)) {
    return [...accumulator, number];
  }

  return accumulator;
}, Promise.resolve([])) || [];

(async () => {
  // no numbers argument provided
  console.log(await filterPositiveNumbersAsync());

  // an empty argument list provided
  console.log(await filterPositiveNumbersAsync([]));

  // ok, but no positive numbers provided
  console.log(await filterPositiveNumbersAsync([-1,-2,-3]));

  // ok, positive numbers filtered.
  console.log(await filterPositiveNumbersAsync([0,1,-1,-3,2,-2]));
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25791940/2714285) I discovered the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) lib which as a [filter function](http://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#filter) handling promises (and much more)

```js
async.filter(['file1','file2','file3'], fs.exists, function(results){
    // results now equals an array of the existing files
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Array.prototype.asyncFilter =function( filterFn) {
       const arr = this;
       return new Promise(function(resolve){
         const booleanArr = [];
         arr.forEach(function (e) { 
            booleanArr.push(filterFn(e))
         })
         Promise.all(booleanArr).then(function (booleanArr) {
           const arr2 = arr.filter(function (e, i) {
             return booleanArr[i]
           })
           resolve(arr2)
         })
       })
    }
/** use it like this**/
const arr=[1,2,3]
arr.asyncFilter(async e=>{}).then(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.filter` from [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.filter.html) that works similarly to `Array.filter` but it supports `async` & `await`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take example:

From 1st glance , you will think intuitively

```
myArray.filter(async (item) => {
  const data = await item.xyz()
  return data.aaa === 'blahblah'
})
```

But, because the callback function is `async`, that's why we are sure that will not work.

Looking into template above, project it into your actual function, and convert it into following  template below.

```
// 1. Map Every Item into Promise
const myPromisesArray = myArray.map(item => item.xyz())
// 2. Wait All Promise to be fulfilled/rejected
const myPromisesResults = await Promise.allSettled(myPromisesArray);
// The Code will not execute the next instructions until all promises above are ready.
// 3. Now filter ( p.value is exactly your "const data" in 1st template)
const filtredPromResults = myPromisesResults.filter(
  p => p.status === 'fulfilled' && p.value.aaa === 'blahblah'
)
// 4. Do something with filtered ( again p.value is same "const data")
filtredPromResults.forEach(p => {
   const data = p.value;
   // do whatever your want with "data"
})
```

Now let's make it reusable,
Let's design it to look like this at the end:

```
filterAsync(array, callbackMapperToPromise, callbackFilter)
```

for our example, we wanna the following to work fine:

```
const list = await filterAsync(
  myArray, 
  (item) => item.json(),
  (data) => data.aaa === 'blahblah'
)
list.forEach(data => /*do whatever*/)
```

Our golden function:

```
async function filterAsync(array, callbackMapperToPromise, callbackFilter) {
    const promises = await Promise.allSettled(array.map(callbackMapperToPromise))
    return promises.filter(
      p => p.status === 'fulfilled' && callbackFilter(p.value)
    ).map(p => p.value)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who use TypeScript and want to extend Array prototype working solution is:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        asyncFilter: <T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown) => Promise<T[]>
    }
}

Array.prototype.asyncFilter = async function<T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown): Promise<T[]> {
    const results = await Promise.all(this.map(predicate))
    return this.filter((_v: T, index: number) => results[index])
}
```

Example usage:

```
async function filterHWID(inputHWID: string) { return await isInDatabase(inputHWID) ? inputHWID : null }
const hwID = [
                '6479_A7FF_F000_0000.',
                '6479_A7FF_F1.',
                'All Series'
            ]
console.log(hwID, '=>', await hwID.asyncFilter(filterHWID))
```

Answer (score -1):

Add asyncFilter as an extension to Array:

```
@available(macOS 10.15.0, *)
extension Array where Element: Any {
    
    public func asyncFilter(closure: (Element) async -> Bool) async -> Array {
        var result = [Element]()
        for item in self {
            if await closure(item) {
                result.append(item)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
result = await result.asyncFilter { item in
    if <item match> {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript / TypeScript