# array filter with async always return all objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to filter an array using async/await, but all elements of array are returning no matter what is the filter predicate.

For example:

```js
[1,2,3].filter(async x => {return false;})
// returns: [1, 2, 3]
[1,2,3].filter(async x => {return})
// returns: [1, 2, 3]
[1,2,3].filter(async x => false)
// returns: [1, 2, 3]
[1,2,3].filter(async x => await false)
// returns: [1, 2, 3]
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: why exactly do you use async/await in this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Array.prototype.filter with async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095019/how-to-use-array-prototype-filter-with-async)

Comment: It's similar, but not exactly, i'm looking for a single line solution to it.
something like

`[1,2,3].filter(async x => await somethingAsync(x) === false)`

Answer (score 0):

What `async` does to your function is to wrap it with a `Promise` which is truthy.

What you want to do instead is

```
const promises = [1, 2, 3].map(n => somethingAsync(n))
const results = await Promise.all(promises);
const filtered = results.filter(r => isOdd(r));
```

Comment: How does this help? The question is to filter an array by a value returned by promise, which presumably needs to be run on each iteration of the filter.

Comment: It may be a solution, but isn't as clean as just doing it on the `.filter` part