# Call API with the result of array.filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, filter

I'm struggling to solve this problem.

To be short, I have an array coming from a request of my database with a deezer_id for each element.
I have a research in my page, and for that i want to filter the data from my database to know if a person like the song or not (kept in DB) et match with the id of the data.
After that i need to pass this id to my api calls to deezer.

But i can't return anything from the api calls inside my filter, i think the fact that filtre is sync block the data.

here is my code

```
        return items = items.filter((item) => {
        var data = this.listOfFavorites /*data from DB which is a query in another func*/
        var idAlbum = item.id_deezer.toString()
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (data[i].attributes.album_id == idAlbum) {

           this.getHisto(item).then(item => {return item})   
          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: return this.getHistory(...

Comment: i tried to add return before the calling the function but it doesn't work.
```
return this.getHisto(item).then(
                  item=> {
                  console.log(item)
                   return item
})
```

The console log works perfectly but i can't extract this data to match the return of items

Comment: you can combine map with filter to achieve your target, use map to getHisto of each item, then you will have an array of these items that you can filter

Comment: it's a little complicated, can you make an example ?

Comment: I found similar solutions to my suggestion here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095019/how-to-use-array-prototype-filter-with-async

Comment: so i would have to make a for loop to get the IDs instead of filter, then call the promise and after the promise is resolve, filter the array coming from the promise ?

Comment: you can use .map() with a callback that returns the promise, so you will have an array of promises, then you can use `await Promise.all(mappedArray)` to get the resolved values of all promises, at this step you will have an array of the returned items and you can filter them normally,