# How can I ensure that my nodejs code runs sequentially while calling Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await

I have 2 database collections and I want to use the result of the first query, as input to the second query, while ensuring the whole code runs sequentially.
Here's what my code looks like:

```
app.post("/Search", async (req, res) => {
    criteria = req.body.criteria
    c = req.body.c
    total = req.body.total
    try {
        const fquery = await db.find(criteria);
        console.log(fquery);//print 1
        let r = fquery.filter(async function (element) {
            let f = element.field;
            console.log(f);//print 2
            const squery = await db2.find({field:f});
            console.log(squery);//print 6
            let cond = squery.length == 0;//result set empty
            if (c == value) {
                cond2 = //some condition
            }
            else if (c == value2) {
                cond2 = //another condition
            }
            else {
                cond2 =//3rd condition
            }
            console.log(cond);//print 7
            console.log(cond2);//print 8
            return (cond || cond2);
        })
        console.log(fquery);//print 3
        console.log("xxxx111");//print 4
        console.log(r);//print 5
        res.json(r);

    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }

});
```

Currently, the code works sequentially till it reaches  (const squery = await db2.find({field:f});) instead of waiting for it to finish, it goes on to the logs after the filter function, in a sequence as I have commented beside each console.log.
I want it to finish the filter function first, then print and send the result to the user. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass two parameters in console log

Assign numbers to check sequence
Ex. Console.log(1,"message or object");

And
Use filter with a collection of promises is to use Promise.all and then apply the function to your collection of results.

Refrence  link  [How to use Array.prototype.filter with async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095019/how-to-use-array-prototype-filter-with-async)

Other case

If Issue related async/await in mongodb .
I mention question related async/await refrence below.

[Node.js mongodb driver async/await queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370487/node-js-mongodb-driver-async-await-queries)